# CRC 16 in matlab

Tags: matlab

i actually want to generate crc in matlab for Modbus protocol and i have used following code in matlab. I have also given message array as `message=uint16([hex2dec('01') hex2dec('02') hex2dec('00') hex2dec('C4') hex2dec('00') hex2dec('16')]);` and done bitand with 0xffff at the end, but it is  unable to give correct crc..

My code is as below and the expected crc is **B839** as per the Modbus crc calculator but it is giving **B8DD**(47325 decimal). Please help me if there is anything to change in the code. Thank you.

```
function crc_val = crc3 (~)
crc = uint16(hex2dec('1D0F'));  % Non-augmented initial value equivalent to augmented initial value 0xFFFF
polynomial = hex2dec('1021'); % Polynomial
message=uint16([hex2dec('01') hex2dec('02') hex2dec('00') hex2dec('C4') hex2dec('00') hex2dec('16') hex2dec('00') hex2dec('00')]);
for i = 1:(length(message)-2) % Not taking the last 2 bytes because they are the CRC.
    crc = bitxor(crc, bitsll(message(i), 8));
    for j = 1:8
        if (bitand(crc, hex2dec('8000')) > 0);
            crc = bitxor(bitsll(crc, 1), polynomial);
        else
            crc = bitsll(crc, 1);
        end
    end
end
crc_val = bitand(crc, hex2dec('ffff'));

end
```

Comment: The linked [CRC 16 FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26741-crc-16/content/crc16.m) contains about 4 lines of actual code which seem to do all that you need. Try understanding those and either use them directly or first try to improve your code based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [this](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26741-crc-16). It is available as BSD license. You would not face any possible licensing issues. The following explains how [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) actually works. The [following](http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/Networks/data.polynomial.html) also helps understand the concept.

```
%usage:  crc16(input vector).
```

//

```
function [resto] = crc16(h)
    % g(X) =  X^16+X^15+X^2+1
    gx = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1];
    % P(X) is given input vector
    px = h;
    %Calculate P(x)x^r
    pxr=[px zeros(1,length(gx)-1)];
    % deconvolve  (r), entre pxr y gx
    [c r]=deconv(pxr,gx);

    r=mod(abs(r),2);
    % returncrc-16
    resto=r(length(px)+1:end);
end
```

Comment: As is this is not an answer (it basically is just a link and if it breaks there is nothing left) I have flagged this to become a comment, but if you can elaborate, explaining what 'this' is and how to use it, of course it can become an answer.

Comment: could you please explain code at (http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26741-crc-16/content/crc16.m) and give some modification tips...I find difficult to understand.

Comment: I donot have matlab installed on my current work machine, however i donot see any reason why this would not work. I added a link on how CRC actually works and tried explain the code.