# CRC-16 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a working program in LabVIEW that I want to port to MATLAB. It takes an input number, converts it to hex, appends it to a constant string (0110 0001 0002 0400 03), calculates a CRC-16, and sends it all to a COM port. Here are two examples for 1500 and 2000 respectively.

```
0110 0001 0002 0400 0305 DCC0 AA
0110 0001 0002 0400 0307 D0C1 CF
```

I can see that dec2hex(1500) produces the 5DC, and dec2hex(2000) produces the 7D0. The AA and the CF are produced by a CRC-16 LabVIEW program, which are 170 and 207 respectively. I understand these are some sort of check-sums, but I can't find a way to reproduce it in MATLAB.

Comment: I would advise you to check this previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987049/crc-16-in-matlab) which deals with the same issue.

Comment: Yes I read that answer - can't figure out how that helps for my particular case.

Comment: So, what is your question exactly here ? Aren't you trying to reproduce the CRC16 on Matlab ?

Comment: Yes. I want to pass it a string, eg, 0110 0001 0002 0400 0305 DC, that produces the checksum, C0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found via: [FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11738-append-crc-for-modbus)

```
 A = ['01';'10';'00';'01';'00';'02';'04';'00';'03';'07';'D0']

 dec2hex(append_crc(hex2dec(A)'))
```

Returns:

`01
10
00
01
00
02
04
00
03
07
D0
C1
CF`